# Image showing in the designer view in VS2013 but not displaying on the phone in wp8

Tags: image, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to display an image inside the page of an app.. It is showing in the designer view of the VS2013 but when I run the app on the phone its not showing..

Following is the xaml :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFFFD9">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="768"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10,12,623">

            <TextBlock Text="" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="118" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="448" Source="images/brandlogo.jpg" RenderTransformOrigin="0.729,0.434" Stretch="Fill"/>

        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="170,628,0,0">

                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="images/statusoffline.bmp" RenderTransformOrigin="0.729,0.434" Stretch="Fill"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: What is the Build Action field from the properties of the image set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Build action is set to Content on the properties of the image file in Visual Studio. That is generally recommended.

Comment: Its strange that one set of images work but when I replace the source with link of another image they are not displayed..

Comment: Check the way you are giving urls. Are all the images in the same folder out of which some are shown and some are not?

Comment: yes all the images are in images folder inside the project directory

Comment: if the images folder is at the root level, try adding a "/" in the beginning.

Comment: yes they are in root level.. I tried that too.. but no luck:(